# change datatable encoding NON ASCII to Unicode in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, ascii, codepages

I have a table in foxpro 2.6 dos version and convert it to a datatable. so far so good. but some character do not display, fields that contain some non_ASCII character. how can i change codepage of a datatable to show all character?

```
public DataTable GetDataTableDBF(string FN) 
{ 
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetFullPath(FileNameStr).Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFile‌​Name(FN), "") + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"); 
    conn.Open(); 
    string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FN) + "]"; 
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sQuery, conn); 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    adapter.Fill(ds); 
    return ds.Tables[0]; 
}
```

Comment: It should work out of the box, a System.Data.DataColumn can be of type string and that string can contain non_ASCII encodings, perhaps you should post yor c# code that reads the foxpro table and stores the string in the datatable. Dont forget the foxpro connection string

Comment: public DataTable GetDataTableDBF(string FN)
        {

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetFullPath(FileNameStr).Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FN), "") + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;");

            conn.Open();

            string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FN) + "]";

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sQuery, conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845760/encoding-problems-with-dbase-iii-dbf-files-on-different-machines Looks like you should use a `OleDbDataReader` and convert the string to the correct encoding. Sample code in the linked question.

Comment: Here is a doc. about codepage   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5b10d8b6(v=vs.80).ASPX